# What are the negative effects of debeaking a chicken?

Tags: behavior, health, chickens

One of my male chickens loves making trouble and gets into fight with the other gentle male chicken almost all the time. An article I read said in this type of cases debeaking the stubborn male is a viable option.

Before doing so, I want to understand the full process of debeaking, I have read some articles but I still need advice on some issues.

What are the negative effects (health and behavioral) that debeaking will have on my chicken?.

Answer (score 12):

Beak-trimming will always cause a deprivation of sensory input in the beak, an important source of information in birds, and the end goal should be the avoidance of beak-trimming altogether through genetics, housing conditions, and management. – Philip C. Glatz, ed., Beak Trimming, 2005, p. 77.

The arguments against debeaking are:

1. Debeaking is often done improperly and in such cases has been shown to be chronically painful to the chicken.
2. Debeaking makes foraging very difficult.
3. Debeaking hinders the chicken from normal preening.
4. Debeaking makes eating more difficult.
5. Some owner's feel that debeaking can be physiologically harmful to the chicken and may make birds act *shell-shocked* and *skittish*

Sources:

- [Poultry Press](http://www.upc-online.org/winter07/debeaking.html)
- [Eggantic Industries](http://www.henspa.com/debeaking.htm)
- [Jessie Knadler's Heartlandia](http://www.babble.com/babble-voices/heartlandia-jessie-knadler/archaic-farming-practices-still-prevail/)

Answer (score 10):

You've already received an excellent answer, but I just wanted to add my recommendation that I feel that beak-trimming should be avoided.

I would also strongly advise against housing roosters together. While there may be some exceptions, in general, housing two males together is going to result in aggression. Beak-trimming may deprive the aggressor of his main "weapon", but it can lead to other problems (difficulty eating, etc.) and is by no means an optimal solution.

Comment: This. The best answer is to not de-beak, and to only house one cock instead.